# Javascript detect keypress keycode unprintable keys

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    this.inputText.on('keypress', function(e){
        if ( String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)) { //or e.keyCode == ""
            valid = true;
            console.log(true);
        } else {
            valid = false;
            console.log(false);
        }
   });
```

I try to detect when keypress, key is printable key (unprintable key - like ctrl + a, or arrow up)

but It never return fasle when I press unprintable key, like arrow down

anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Use `keydown` event and detect [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead of `keyCode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `keydown`, not `keypress`. The whole point of `keypress` is that it's for keys that result in a printable character.

Comment: i forgot to add  String.fromCharCode()